# link div to radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I am struggling to link div to radio button, I have tried below code which is not working for me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#three">
        <input name="ROS_services" type="radio" id="display3">
    </a>
    <p>Display 3</p>

    <div id="one">
        <p>one</p>

    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <p>two</p>

    </div>
    <div id="three">
        <p>three</p>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please assist me with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your Javascript code if there's any?

Comment: What do you mean by "link" the div to the radio button? Are you talking about visibility?

Comment: what behavior are you looking for? Do you want it to hide/show the div?

Comment: instead of radio button if i use <p> will work, as below

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```html
<input name="ROS_services" type="radio" name="display" id="display1" />
<input name="ROS_services" type="radio" name="display" id="display2" />
<input name="ROS_services" type="radio" name="display" id="display3" />

<br />
<br />

<label for="display1">label1</label><br />
<label for="display2">label2</label><br />
<label for="display3">label3</label><br />
```

or this:

```css
div {
  display:none;
}

#display1[type=radio]:checked ~ #div1 {
   display:block;
}
#display2[type=radio]:checked ~ #div2 {
   display:block;
}
#display3[type=radio]:checked ~ #div3 {
   display:block;
}
```

```html
    <input name="ROS_services" type="radio" name="display" id="display1" />
    <input name="ROS_services" type="radio" name="display" id="display2" />
    <input name="ROS_services" type="radio" name="display" id="display3" />

<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some javascript here. Let me show you:

```
 // Place this before the </body> tag

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#radio-link").click(function () {
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; // Put your link here
    });
    </script>

 // And give an id to your radio input like this

    <input type="radio" id="radio-link">Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for me.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function radioSelected()
{

window.location.href = "#three";

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="radio" id="display1" onClick="radioSelected();">

<div id="one">
<p>one</p>

</div>
<div id="two">
<p>two</p>

</div>
<div id="three">
<p>three</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks everyone